# Bootstrap Alert showing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following issue: I have created some alerts using Bootstrap. Initially, these are hidden. When a rating is given (using raty), an Ajax request is send. When this returns successfully, an alert is shown and a timer is started. When the timer runs out, the alert disappears. I am 100% sure that my Ajax requests are being successful.

There are 2 problems with this.

- Firstly, when the alert disappears, it leaves a blank space on the page, where it used to be.
- Secondly, when another rating is given, the Ajax request is fired again but the alert is not shown anymore.

How can I fix these problems?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id='rateSuccess' class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in' role='alert' hidden>
    <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
         <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> Your rating is saved!
</div>

<div id='rateError' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissable fade in' role='alert' hidden>
    <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
         <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
    </button>
    <strong>Error!</strong> You must be logged in to give a rating!
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    $('#rating').raty({
        path: '../images',
        click: function(score, evnt) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/publication/rate/' + pubID,
                data: {'score': score},
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                    var success = data.success;
                    if (success) {
                        $('#rateSuccess').toggle();
                        startTimeout('#rateSuccess');
                    } else {
                        var type = data.type;
                        if (type === 'server') {
                            $('#serverAlert').toggle();
                            startTimeout('#serverAlert');
                        } else if (type === 'loggedin') {
                            $('#rateError').toggle();
                            startTimeout('#rateError');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    );

    function startTimeout(id) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(id).fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
                $(id).toggle(); 
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqb1y6k1/

Comment: To assist you, please create fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$(id).toggle();` from your timeout (as the alert is already hidden by `.slideUp()`), and set opacity of the element to `1` inside AJAX `success`/`error` callback:

```
$('#rateSuccess').css('opacity', 1).slideDown();
```

---

`.fadeTo()` sets opacity of the element, while `.slideUp()` is setting the CSS to `display:none;`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bejmvxtx/)